# Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1) fortran

Tags: rank, incompatibletypeerror

I try to write a code but get the error on the top, my code is below. please help me.(I search the web but cannt solve the problem)

```
program deneme
  implicit none 
  integer::i,mtd
  integer, parameter :: M = 100
  real, parameter:: pi = 3.1415926535897932
  double precision   xedge(0 : M) , xcell(0 : M-1)
  double precision Uext(0 : M-1) 
  double precision Uold(0 : M-1)
  double precision Unew(0 : M-1)
  double precision:: t_final, time, dt, xa, xb, dx, cfl,a

  cfl = 1.0d0
  t_final = 1.0d0 
  time = 0.0d0
  a = 1.0d0

  xa = 0.0d0 ; xb = 1.0d0
  dx = (xb - xa)/M
  dt =  cfl * (dx /dabs(a))
  do i = 0, M-1 
      xedge(i) = xa + i*dx
      xcell(i) = xa + (i+1./2.)*dx
  enddo
      xedge(M) = xa + M*dx
      !print *, "dx =",dx,dt,xa,xb 

  do i=0,M-1
       Uold(i) = [-dcos(2.0d0 * pi * xedge(i+1) )
 &            + dcos(2.0d0 * pi * xedge(i) )]/(2.0d0 * pi * dx)
       Uext(i) = dsin(2.0d0 * pi * (xedge(i)-a*time) )
       !write(11,*)xcell(i),uold(i),uext(i),dabs(uext(i)- uold(i)) 
  enddo

  do while (time <= t_final)
        time = time + dt
        do i = 1 , M-2
          Unew(i) = Uold(i) - dt*(Uold(i+1)-Uold(i-1)) / (2.0d0*dx)
 &  + 2*dt*dt*( Uold(i+1) - 2*Uold(i) + Uold(i-1) ) / (2.0d0*dx*dx)

          Unew(0) = Uold(0) - dt*(Uold(1)-Uold(M-1)) / (2.0d0*dx)
 &  + 2*dt*dt*( Uold(1) - 2*Uold(0) + Uold(M-1) ) / (2.0d0*dx*dx)

          Unew(M-1) = Unew(0)                

          Uext(i) = dsin(2.0d0 * pi * (xedge(i)-a*time) )
          Uext(0) = dsin(2.0d0 * pi * (xedge(0)-a*time) )
          Uext(M-1) = dsin(2.0d0 * pi * (xedge(M)-a*time) )
        enddo
        Uold = Unew

        !print*,"dt=",dt," time =",time
  enddo

  do i=0, M-1
      print*, Uext(i), Unew(i), dabs(Uext(i)- Unew(i))
     ! write(20,*)xedge(i), Uext(i), Unew(i), dabs(Uext(i)- Unew(i)) 

  enddo

  END
```

Comment: please give the whole error. the (1) referenced in the error actually points to where the error actually happened. otherwise, one has to go through your code and figure out what is wrong. that is too much work!

Answer (score 0):

you only need to a few modifications to your program, kindly replace the '[]' with '()' 
in your first do loop defining the array Uold, and the '&' should be the last character of the line which is to be continued to the next line, 
once you make these modifications, the program runs fine